# Set inline SVG fill color by CSS related to outside classname

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to load a SVG several times on my html page, and change the color of a path to different values related to a class outside the svg:

```
.red svg path {
  fill: #ff0000;
}

.green svg path {
  fill: #00ff00;
}
```

But is does not work. All the paths have the color of the first svg on the page.

Why is it like that, and what are the possibilities to have the same inline SVG with different fill colors on one page?

I build a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1p0svg9u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use the ID "Pattern" twice. Each ID may only be used once, or the browser will only interpret the first occurrence. The second SVG refers to the first pattern and is therefore red. Just rename the second ID.

```css
.red {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.red svg path {
  fill: #ff0000;
}

.green svg path {
  fill: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class='red'>
      <p>
        Red triangles
      </p>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 10000 20" width="10000" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width=".006" height="20">
            <path d="M15 10L0 0L30 0L60 0L45 10L30 20L15 10Z"></path>      
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" width="10000" height="20"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    
    <div class='green'>
      <p>
        Green triangles
      </p>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 10000 20" width="10000" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="Patterntwo" x="0" y="0" width=".006" height="20">
            <path d="M15 10L0 0L30 0L60 0L45 10L30 20L15 10Z"></path>      
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect fill="url(#Patterntwo)" width="10000" height="20"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should use Stack Overflow's Code Snippet feature to create live examples, rather than linking offsite - [How to create Code Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @Light: Thank you! Of course, the svg code is part of the dom, so an ID can only be used once. I`m using ng-inline-svg, and now just manipulate the id for each instance.
Another solution could be to have a shadow dom for the svg, but this would be complex in my case.